# Facebook login with Express

Tags: node.js, facebook, express, mongoose, passport-facebook

I'm making a Facebook login with Express, mongoose and passport / passport-facebook modules for nodejs.

I want to handle with a controller who i created for authenticate. When i activate the server, trigger that message on terminal:

```
  if (!verify) { throw new TypeError('OAuth2Strategy requires a verify callback
                       ^
TypeError: OAuth2Strategy requires a verify callback
```

This is my code:

**userController**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var passport = require('passport');
var FacebookStrategy = require('passport-facebook').Strategy;
var Account = require('../models/accounts');
var Project = require('../models/projects');
var Message = require('../models/messages');
var Follow = require('../models/follows');
var apiKeys = require('../apiKeys');

{more code}

fbAuth : function(access_token, refresh_token, profile, done){
        console.log("*************");
        console.log("entra en fbAuth");
        console.log("*************");
        Account.findOne({'providerId' : profile.id}, function(err, user){
          if(err){
            return done(err);
          }
          if(user){
            return done(null, user);
          }
          else{
            var newUser = new Account({
              emailAccount : profile.emails[0].value,
              provider : profile.provider,
              providerId : profile.id,
              username : profile.name.givenName,
            });
            newUser.save();
          }
        });
      passport.authenticate('facebook',{
        successRedirect : '/user',
        failureRedirect : '/'
      });
    },
    fbAuthSuccess : function (req, res){
      passport.authenticate('facebook', {
        successRedirect : '/user',
        failureRedirect : '/'
      });
    },
```

**route**

```
router.get('/facebook', controller.fbAuth);//passport.authenticate('facebook', { scope : 'email' }));
router.get('/facebook/callback', passport.authenticate('facebook', {
  successRedirect : '/user',
  failureRedirect : '/'
});
```

**app.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var morgan = require('morgan');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var FacebookStrategy = require('passport-facebook').Strategy;
var session = require('express-session');
var socket = require('socket.io');
var apiKeys = require('./apiKeys');
var app = express();

{more code}

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(Account.authenticate()));
passport.serializeUser(Account.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(Account.deserializeUser());

//social facebook
passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
  clientID: apiKeys.facebook.appID,
  clientSecret: apiKeys.facebook.appSecret,
  callbackURL: apiKeys.facebook.callbackUrl,
  'profileFields': ['id', 'displayName', 'email', 'name'],
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a verify callback, your `controller.fbAuth` as a second argument to `passport.use`. The `router.get('/facebook` should have `passport.authenticate('facebook')` as its second argument. You can follow the example on [passports docs](http://passportjs.org/docs/facebook).

Comment: explain better please, more graphical.